# Change first page in memoir package

Tags: memoir, double-sided

I've got a book in LaTeX, using the `memoir` package with the options: `[smalldemyvopaper,12pt,twoside,onecolumn,openright,extrafontsizes]`

I'm creating an alternating gap for the binding using

```latex
\setbinding{0.175in}
\setlrmarginsandblock{0.611in}{1.222in}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{0.722in}{1.545in}{*}
```

However, my book starts on the wrong side. While books should start on the right side, with the gap on the left for the binding, mine is the opposite. Furthermore, when I use `\openleft` on my chapters, it causes them to actually open on the right! Somehow my setup is reversed or something.

Here are all my options at the top of the doc, if that helps clear anything up.

```latex
% universal settings \documentclass[smalldemyvopaper,12pt,twoside,onecolumn,openright,extrafontsizes]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[osf]{Alegreya,AlegreyaSans}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[x-1a:2001]{pdfx}
%\usepackage[osf]{tgschola}
% PACKAGE DEFINITION
% typographical packages
\usepackage{microtype} % for micro-typographical adjustments
\usepackage{setspace} % for line spacing
\usepackage{lettrine} % for drop caps and awesome chapter beginnings
\usepackage{titlesec} % for manipulation of chapter titles
% for placeholder text
\usepackage{lipsum} % to generate Lorem Ipsum
% other
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{hologo}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
%\usepackage{showframe}
% PHYSICAL DOCUMENT SETUP
% media settings
\setstocksize{8in}{5in}
\settrimmedsize{8in}{5in}{*}
\setbinding{0.175in}
\setlrmarginsandblock{0.611in}{1.222in}{*} %odd pages
\setulmarginsandblock{0.722in}{1.545in}{*} %even pages
\openleft
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  Is that just a typo -- you have `openright` as one of the document class options.

Comment: Hello there! This is Tom from the Overleaf Support Team. Please note that I removed the [tag:overleaf] tag as this is not directly overleaf-related.

Answer (score 1):

I expanded your partial MWE into a complete one by adding `\begin{document} lots of text \end{document}`

I had a problem or two with your code. (a) `\usepackage[x-1a:2001]{pdfx}` was reported as invalid, cured by deleting the `:2001` (b) an option clash was reported for the `hyperref` package (c) after changing the margins you should have called `\checkandfixthelayout` (d) you used class option `openright` but later called `\openleft`.

However, ignoring all these the output was as you wanted. First page was a right (recto, odd) page. Chapters all started on left (verso) pages. If I deleted your `\openleft` then chapters started on odd pages.

In books the inner page margins are narrower than the outer margins so that when the book is opened to a double page spread (left and right pages) the two outer margins are the same size as the space between the left and right textblocks (inner margins about half outer margins).